# How to use $wpdb->prepare with WHERE NOT EXISTS to prevent duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In WordPress Development Stack Exchange, I [answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141845/22728) my own Question where I mentioned that, with the following code I'm able to insert data into database, but can prevent duplicate entries:

```
  INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
            ( user_id, post_id )
            VALUES ( %d, %d )
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM
              {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.user_id = user_id
              AND
              {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.post_id = post_id
            )
```

I don't know why, it's actually **NOT working** (I don't know how it worked that time!!). Now I modified my code into this:

```
  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
            ( user_id, post_id )
            VALUES ( %d, %d )
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM
                {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
              WHERE
                {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.user_id = VALUES({$user_id})
                AND
                {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.post_id = VALUES({$post_id[1]})
            )
        ", 
        $user_id, 
        $post_id[1]
    ) );
```

But still it's not working, even it's failing to insert the data into db.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it at last with two different queries - I agree, not a smarter one, but at least solved my one, as all the other possibilities are a mixture of two queries:

```
        $alreadyGot = $wpdb->get_results(
                            "SELECT
                            COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT
                            FROM {$table}
                            WHERE ( user_id = $user_id AND post_id = $post_id[1] )
                                AND ( order_id = '' )"
                        );

        $count = $alreadyGot[0]->TOTALCOUNT;

        if( $count > 0 ) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            $wpdb->insert( 
                $table,
                array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'post_id' => $post_id[1]
                )
            );
        }
```

Thanks to my colleague Mr. Ariful Haque.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to use a `where` clause with `insert ... values ...`. Try using `insert ... select ... where ...` instead:

```
 INSERT INTO
     {$wpdb->prefix}user_req (
         user_id,
         post_id
      )
SELECT
    %d,
    %d
FROM
    DUAL
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            0
        FROM
              {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
        WHERE
            {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.user_id = user_id
        AND
            {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.post_id = post_id
    )
```

Comment: I'm afraid, not inserting data. :(

Comment: Changed it already. Can you try again? And afterwards please post your errors, if any.

Comment: I'm using AJAX, with `$wpdb->print_error();` I got the exact query as you offered above, with just two respective values after `SELECT` as `1, 25`. Rest is same, and the result is, NOT INSERTING, even new entries. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
            ( user_id, post_id )
            VALUES ( %d, %d )
            WHERE 0 = (
              SELECT count(*)
              FROM
                {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
              WHERE
                {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.user_id = VALUES({$user_id})
                AND
                {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.post_id = VALUES({$post_id[1]})
            )
        ", 
        $user_id, 
        $post_id[1]
    ) );
```

Comment: Uhu! That's totally erroneous! :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues - first using `INSERT/SELECT` utilizing the `DUAL` dummy table name is recommended (only returning the values when the result of the subquery is 0), however to properly execute the subquery you will need to pass your parameters in twice. Using a table alias can make things easier to manage. See the example below.

```
// Set up your query using HEREDOC format
$sql = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}user_req 
( user_id, post_id )
SELECT %d, %d
FROM DUAL
WHERE 0 = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}user_req AS ur
    WHERE ur.user_id = %d
    AND ur.post_id = %d
SQL;

// Call prepare(), pass values first for INSERT, and again for the sub SELECT
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $user_id, $post_id[1], $user_id, $post_id[1] );

// Execute the query
$wpdb->query( $sql );
```

Comment: Unexpected result! All the `$_POST['id']` after the code is marked red - when refreshed the browser screen, a notice appeared: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING**.

Comment: `$_POST['id']` is no where in your, or my, example. I think you have some general syntax errors.